# SQL Server: query database user roles for all databases in server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, select

I would like to make a query for database user roles for all databases in my sql server instance. I modified a query from sp_helpuser:

```
select  u.name
        ,case when (r.principal_id is null) then 'public' else r.name end
        ,l.default_database_name
        ,u.default_schema_name
        ,u.principal_id
from sys.database_principals u
    left join (sys.database_role_members m join sys.database_principals r on m.role_principal_id = r.principal_id) 
        on m.member_principal_id = u.principal_id
    left join sys.server_principals l on u.sid = l.sid
    where u.type <> 'R'
```

How can I modify this to query from all databases? What is the link between sys.databases and sys.database_principals?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the stored procedure `sp_msforeachdb`

> sp_msforeachdb: This is a very useful
>   system stored procedure that will
>   execute any SQL script you pass to for
>   in each of the databases on your SQL
>   Server instance. The stored procedure
>   just loops through the databases,
>   which is simple to write, but it saves
>   you from having to do it yourself.

Add a column for the database name and a [?] placeholder for the the database name and then execute the script within the `sp_msforeachdb` stored proc like this:

```
EXECUTE sp_msforeachdb 'select  ''[?]'' as DatabaseName,
             u.name
            ,case when (r.principal_id is null) then ''public'' else r.name end
            ,l.default_database_name
            ,u.default_schema_name
            ,u.principal_id
    from [?].sys.database_principals u
        left join ([?].sys.database_role_members m join [?].sys.database_principals r on m.role_principal_id = r.principal_id) 
            on m.member_principal_id = u.principal_id
        left join [?].sys.server_principals l on u.sid = l.sid
        where u.type <> ''R'''
```

To get this all in one table you would have to create a table in one database, we'll use the `master` as an example.

Create the table in the `master` database

```
Create Table master.dbo.userPermissionResults
(
....
)
```

Then simply add the insert statement to the start of the query

```
EXECUTE sp_msforeachdb 'Insert Into master.dbo.userPermissionResults select  ''[?]'' as DatabaseName,
             u.name
            ,case when (r.principal_id is null) then ''public'' else r.name end
            ,l.default_database_name
            ,u.default_schema_name
            ,u.principal_id
    from [?].sys.database_principals u
        left join ([?].sys.database_role_members m join [?].sys.database_principals r on m.role_principal_id = r.principal_id) 
            on m.member_principal_id = u.principal_id
        left join [?].sys.server_principals l on u.sid = l.sid
        where u.type <> ''R'''
```

You must specify the database name for the `Insert` statement otherwise it will try to insert the data into the current database.

Comment: Neat! Is there a simple way to get this into a table (or into a same grid)?

Comment: I have updated my answer with details on how to insert the data into one table. HTH Barry

Comment: i did this with a temp table, since its still within scope, it will let you save results. Table variables won't work.